# facebook wall post error 341

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall, error-code

I am getting following error while posting on a friends wall, saying "Feed action request limit reached ". What is the exact limit of doing such feed reqest? Where can I find documentation related to this?

```
    $error : Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t 
        be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" 
        UserInfo=0x6ae32f0 
       {error=<CFBasicHash
           0x6ae2fe0 [0x132fb38]>{type = mutable dict, count = 3, entries =>
           $2 : <CFString 0x6aa0e30 [0x132fb38]>{contents = "type"} = 
                <CFString 0x6ae3190 [0x132fb38]>{contents = "OAuthException"}
           $3 : <CFString 0x6ae3130 [0x132fb38]>{contents = "message"} = 
                <CFString 0x6ae30d0 [0x132fb38]>{contents = "(#341) Feed action 
                    request limit reached"}
           $6 : <CFString 0x6ae3230 [0x132fb38]>{contents = "code"} = 341
}
}
```